# Equivalent of -DPREPROC_VAR for rust/cargo

Tags: rust, constants, rust-cargo

I have a `const` variable that I need to be hardcoded at runtime but configurable at compile time. In C/C++ style preprocessors one can typically tell the compile `-DPREPROC_VAR` and guard the definition with an `#ifndef` like

```
#ifndef MAX_TRHEADS
#define MAX_THREADS 1000
#endif
```

In rust I have

```rust
// Doesn't actually work because I need a usize and `env!` returns `&str`
const MAX_THREADS: usize = std::env!("MYLIB_MAX_THREADS");
```

but I can't figure out how to set a default value for it. I tried setting `MYLIB_MAX_THREADS` in the `[env]` section in Cargo.toml but it didn't work.

Comment: Note that `env!()` (and `option_env!()`) are in the prelude, you don't need to fully qualify them - `std::env!()`.

Answer (score 2):

`env!` require the variable to be here so have a default value make no sense. However `option_env!` it could make sense:

```rust
const MAX_THREADS: &'static str = {
    if let Some(x) = std::option_env!("MYLIB_MAX_THREADS") {
        x
    } else {
        "42"
    }
};
```

Comment: I was going to suggest shortening this to `std::option_env!("MYLIB_MAX_THREADS").unwrap_or("42")`, but unfortunately [`unwrap_or` isn't `const` yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/91930) on stable. Hopefully someday, though :)

Comment: I really do need a `usize` thoug. `&str` is not going to cut it. Is there a `const` way to parse the `&str`?

Comment: @fakedrake make another question, and before search for the answer